# How to log a variable onlineID to Gatling logs

Tags: scala, automated-tests, gatling

I am new to scala and Gatling.

When Gatling does a check for a status 200 I want to include a variable onlineID into the logs so that I know which user had an issue.

```
 object MyRequests{
    val getAddressForOnlineId = feed(Configuration.csvFeeder)
      .exec(
      http("Abfrage von Adressdaten")
        .get(Configuration.baseUrl + "/myrequest/${myonlineID}" )
        .headers(Configuration.globalHeaders)
        .check(status.is(200))
    )
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the status in your check with `saveAs` and then in an `exec(function)` block, extract the status and myonlineID values from the Session and print into your own file or slf4j logger when status is not 200.

I recommend you have a look at the [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/frontline/) and [Gatling Academy](https://gatling.io/academy/).

Comment: I think I am going to use this solution as it is easier to implement for me...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293588/gatling-log-body-of-request-in-simulation-log-or-console

Comment: extraInfoExtractor has been removed years ago

Comment: Oh good to know - that's why it did not work :-)
Ok then I will. have to try out your answer again tomorrow.